# (gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.build) HTTPError 412

Tags: google-cloud-platform, flexbox, storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am going to build the dataflow example flex template 'getting_started-java', after I prepared all necessary role and permission, I still got one error which block my build.
my command roughly like below.
`gcloud dataflow flex-template build gs://$BUCKETNAME/getting_started-java.json \ --image-gcr-path "europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/my-project-id/test-repository/getting-started-java:latest" \ --sdk-language "JAVA" \ --dataflow-kms-key="projects/kms-project-id/locations/europe-west2/keyRings/computeEngine/cryptoKeys/computeEngine" \ --flex-template-base-image JAVA11 \ --metadata-file "metadata.json" \ --jar "target/flex-template-getting-started-1.0.jar" \ --env FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS="com.example.dataflow.FlexTemplateGettingStarted"`

got below error.
***ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.build) HTTPError 412: A default customer-managed encryption key (CMEK) on the bucket is required by an org policy in effect. Learn more at https://cloud.google.com/km
s/docs/cmek-org-policy#require-cmek***

but actually my bucket on gcp has custom-managed cmek, see below.
[has custom-managed cmek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcVEY.png)

anyone hit the same error and any solution? Many thanks.

I have tried to recreate the bucket with the same custom-managed cmek, I still can not solve the problem.
I tested to upload and download object from the bucket and success, which means network and permission is all ok.

Comment: Have you checked https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/customer-managed-encryption-keys?

Comment: yes, I have computeEngine cmek for datafow and cloudStorage cmek for gcp bucket.